# Lazy load json data Gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I am using gatsby version 2. I would like to display a table and the data comes from json.

```
import jsonData from '../data/jsonData';

function PricingComponent() {
 return <Table data={jsonData} />
}
```

It works just fine. However, since the JSON file is large, this affects badly on the first load time. How could I lazy load the JSON data?

Comment: Please provide feedback about the resolution. Has the issue been solved? How?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`loadable` components](https://loadable-components.com/)?

```
const jsonData = loadable(() => import('../data/jsonData'))

function PricingComponent() {
 return <Table data={jsonData} />
}
```

I'm not sure if it will "lazy-load" as is but you will be splitting as an alternative.

Alternatively, you can try using `loadable` on your `PricingComponent` in the same way.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I decided to upgrade gatsby version first. I will come back to this issue later